# Where do i get Cordova 3.4.js?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am working with Sencha Touch. I need the latest **Cordova 3.4.js** (That **Javascript file only**) to build my project. The only resource known for me is Phonegap thing. But the latest available Phonegap archive version is 2.9.1. But I need Ver 3.4.0 and Included Cordova 3.4.0.js for android & iOS. Can anyone help me on this ??

Answer (score 2):

You can get the .zip file here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-js/releases/tag/3.4.0
Just extract the JavaScript file.

Comment: I cant see any Cordova.js/ Cordova 3.4.0.js file inside the extracted folder !!

Comment: It's in the src folder once you unzip the downloaded package. It's not called cordova3.4.0.js - simply 'cordova.js' but the package version is cordova.3.4.0. You can just rename the file 'cordova3.4.js' or whatever your CMS/program needs it to be called.

Comment: You mean that 8 KB file ?? I think its not the one which I needed. because my cordova 2.9.1.js was about 223 KB..!!!

Comment: In cordova 3.x cordova.js does not contain any plugin anymore that explain why it's smaller. (android cordova.js is 56kb) It then uses require to include plugins that are added to the project.

Answer (score 2):

For cordova 3.4/Phonegap 3.4 you should be using the Command Line Interface to create/build your projects.

cordova.js is automatically added to the project when you run either `cordova build ios` or `cordova build android`.

The content of the cordova.js is dependant of the platform you build for and it loads other scripts files, like for example plugins. You can't just copy the cordova.js file like you used to with cordova <3.0.
You could find the cordova.js in the zip as refered in previous answer (in platforms dependent subfolders), but again, you'd really better use the CLI.

Comment: I am creating Sencha Project and using Cordova.js just for building purpose. Thats why I needed Cordova.js only. I am not creating Cordova Project !

Comment: if you followed sencha's guide in their docs, you wouldn't need to ask this question as sencha cmd would automatically add the cordova file to your builds.

Answer (score 0):

No worry about that. After you build your cordova project for iOS and android, already there.

iOS

[image]

Android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hope so it helps....
(1 install ecipse or ADT

http://w3stream.blogspot.in/2014/02/phonegap-34-environment-setup-and.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

Cordova.js Now uses requires.js. it will be hard to just find Cordova.js file and put it in your project and expect it to work.... You will find it after u use the build command(if u know what I mean)