# cordova.js is accidentally deleted from the eclipse

Tags: cordova

I accidentally delete cordova.js from my eclipse.. My project was build in cordova 3.4.0. I copy a cordova.js of version 3.4.0 and paste to the www in eclipse. But the application is not running. It is detecting some syntax error on the last line of the cordova.js. Is there any method to overcome this problem? 
is cordova.js unique for each project? Thank you.

Comment: Try clearing the project and rebuilding it.

Comment: i have already tried it. it's not working.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689277/where-do-i-get-cordova-3-4-js) may help.